# Convert IPV6 to IPV4 Vertica

Tags: ipv6, vertica, ipv4

Just wanted to share.
Tested with Vertica 9.0.
Credit also goes to Debra Dalgleish, who's blog page helped me out initially
https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2018/03/29/excel-easter-dates-and-ip-addresses/

```
  select 
        ipv6,
        -- hex01,
        -- hex02,
        -- hex03,
        -- hex04,
        -- ip01,
        -- ip02,
        -- ip03,
        -- ip04,
        concat(concat(concat(ip01,'.'),concat(ip02,'.')),concat(concat(ip03,'.'),ip04)) ipv4
        from
        (
                select 
                ip ipv6,  /* <== this is the column where the IPV6 is located */
                left(right(ip, 9),2) hex01,
                substring(right(ip, 9),3,2) hex02,
                substring(right(ip, 9),6,2) hex03,
                right(right(ip,9),2) hex04,
                HEX_TO_INTEGER(left(right(ip, 9),2)) ip01,
                HEX_TO_INTEGER(substring(right(ip, 9),3,2)) ip02,
                HEX_TO_INTEGER(substring(right(ip, 9),6,2)) ip03,
                HEX_TO_INTEGER(right(right(ip,9),2)) ip04                
                from <table name>
          ) a;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: The proper way to do this is to ask a question, then post your own answer to the question.